# Apache poi как создать колонки в excel

Tags: java, apache, excel

Я создал таблицу в table view и теперь вывожу её в excel через apache poi вот таким вот образом:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Main_Information");
        HSSFRow row;


        for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
            spreadsheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(30);
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
            ObservableList<String> currentRow = (ObservableList<String>) tableView.getItems().get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < currentRow.size(); j++) {
                row.createCell(j).setCellValue(currentRow.get(j));
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Main_Information.xls");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            workbook.write(fileOut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

И вот в чем проблема первых всю информацию он выводит в текстовом формате, во вторых он выводит только строки, но не выводит названия колонок, мне нужно что бы он выводил названия колонок, а так же что бы к каждой ячейке присваивал определенный тип данных, это вообще возможно?

Comment: В документации вроде как доступно все описано.

Comment: Я просматривал документацию, но ничего не нашел

Comment: Всё возможно. Создавай Cell отдельно, и там можно и формат присваивать и что хочешь. А по поводу названия колонок, перед currentRow создай ещё одну Cell